# Can the compiler decide the noexcept'ness of a function?

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, noexcept

Let's do an example

```
class X
{
    int value;
public:
    X (int def = 0) : value (def) {}

    void add (int i)
    {
        value += i;
    }
};
```

Clearly, the function `void X::add (int)` will never throw any exception.

My question is, can the compiler analyze the code and decide not to generate machine code to handle exceptions, even if the function is not marked as `noexcept`?

Comment: I'm curious, why would you want (to know) this?

Comment: Have you *checked* the code generated by your compiler?

Comment: It *can*, just like it *can* tell whether a function is `const` or not, or `constexpr`. It's a compiler after all. Whether it *does indeed* do that and whether it *does use* that information is another question.

Comment: "Clearly, the function `void X::add (int)` will never throw any exception." -- Probably true for the particular compilers you and I are using, but it wouldn't surprise me if some compiler has an option to throw exceptions on signed integer overflow.

Answer (score 7):

If the compiler can prove that a function will never throw, it is allowed by the "As-If" rule (§1.9, "Program execution" of the C++ standard) to remove the code to handle exceptions.

However it is not possible to decide if a function will never throw *in general*, as it amounts to solving the Halting Problem.